# How to implement a dynamic temperature conversion method based on given enums?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am making some basic temperature conversion methods, and I want the end result to look something like this:

```
double celsius = TemperatureConvert.convert(10, Temperature.FAHRENHEIT, Temperature.CELSIUS);
// Where 'Temperature' is an enum with three values: FAHRENHEIT, CELSIUS, and KELVIN
// This mehtod is read logically as "convert 10 degrees fahrenheit to celsius"
```

Originally, I thought that the best approach was to have some private methods inside `TemperatureConvert` to do the conversion for me. I quickly discovered I was wrong. I want to make this method dynamic, so I used my Google Fu and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935709/call-a-specific-method-based-on-enum-type). If you don't want to read it, the answers basically tell OP about the ability to have an abstract method in the enum class, and then have each enum override it.

I am having some trouble figuring out the best approach. Here are the two possibilities I came up with:

1. Create *two* abstract methods, `convertA()` and `convertB()`. Have `convertA()` convert to the unit that is first in alphabetical order, and have `convertB()` convert the other unit. In the `TemperatureConvert.convert()` method, I can figure out what method to use by comparing the enum name. This also brings up an issue if the same unit is passed into the `convert()` method, as there is no method to do any conversion. However, no conversion is needed so that might not be a problem.
2. Create *three* abstract methods, `convertToCelsius()`, `convertToFahrenheit()`, and `convertToKelvin()`. Use a switch statement to decide which method to use.

Comment: +1 The question doesn't consist any codes but still serves the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` enum class provides both a [generic conversion method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) and specific methods for each modeled unit, e.g., [`toHours`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toHours%28long%29). You could do something similar and still provide the third-party `TemperatureConvert.convert` method if you want.

Here's the implementation of `SECONDS`:

```
SECONDS {
    public long toNanos(long d)   { return x(d, C3/C0, MAX/(C3/C0)); }
    public long toMicros(long d)  { return x(d, C3/C1, MAX/(C3/C1)); }
    ...
    public long toHours(long d)   { return d/(C5/C3); }
    ...
    public long convert(long d, TimeUnit u) { return u.toSeconds(d); }
},
```

Note that the author went for efficiency by precalculating many of the conversion constants. I wouldn't bother with that to start as it's probably premature for your needs. Your conversion methods should start simply:

```
CELCIUS {
    public double toFahrenheit(long t) {
        return t * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }
    public double toKelven(long t) {
        return t + 273;
    }
    public double convert(double t, TemperatureUnit u) {
        return u.toCelcius(v);
    }
}
```

Also, all of the conversion methods are stubs that throw an exception rather than abstract. Why? I don't know. If these weren't enums and could be extended, stub methods that fail only when called are handy for allowing optional operations--think `Collection.remove(Object)` which throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if not implemented by the concrete container.

Comment: If you are talking about TimeUnit, then yes, they throw an `AbstractMethodError` if not overridden. It also gives a reference to [Bug JDK-6287639](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6287639).

Comment: @whowantsakookie - So the author made the parent methods concrete to avoid an unresolved feature request in JavaDoc? That's a serious commitment to API documentation clarity. :)